# How to connect Ubuntu server to laptop network

Tags: networking, server, ssh, ethernet, tunnel

I have a headless raspberry pi running Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS.  I control it with my laptop through an Ethernet cable.

I’d like to remove the Ethernet cable. There is an interface ‘wlan0’ that I believe I can use for that, but I’m lost on how to.

‘ip address add 169.254.77.77 dev wlan0’ adds an inet address under wlan0. Then I need a way to connect to that IP address from my laptop. My goal is to be able to run ‘ssh ubuntu@169.254.77.77’ and connect to it without an Ethernet cable, and without connection to internet.

Answer (score 0):

Interface `wlan0` is, as the name indicates, intended to connect to a WLAN (Wireless Local Area Network), also known as a WiFi network. So you need a WLAN to which you connect both your server and your laptop. Most home internet routers will provide that capability. You will then have to configure your server with the name (SSID) and access password of the WLAN you intend to use.

Also make sure you have connected a WLAN antenna to your server, otherwise you won't be able to make a wireless connection at all.

The IP address for your server will typically be assigned by the WLAN router, so you shouldn't assign on the server itself, and certainly not one out of the APIPA range 169.254.*.*.